# how to set tab index radmultipage when postback occurs dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, tabs, postback, telerik-grid

**Code**

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" OnTabClick="RadTabScript1_TabClick" OnClientTabSelecting="onTabSelecting" >  <%-- OnClientTabSelecting="onTabSelecting"> --%>
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Resources" runat="server" TabIndex="0" Selected="true" PageViewID="radPageResources"></telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Tasks" runat="server" TabIndex="1" PageViewID="radPageTasks"></telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Messages" runat="server" TabIndex="2" PageViewID="radPageMessages"></telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Files" runat="server" TabIndex="3" PageViewID="radPageFiles"></telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Feedback" runat="server" TabIndex="4" PageViewID="radPageFeedback"></telerik:RadTab>
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" OnPageViewCreated="RadMultiPage1_PageViewCreated" SelectedIndex="0" >  <%--  RenderSelectedPageOnly="true"  >  --%>
<telerik:RadPageView ID="radPageResources" runat="server" TabIndex="0">
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdResource" PageSize="5" Skin="Default" AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="97%"
    OnItemCreated="grdResource_ItemCreated" OnNeedDataSource="grdResource_NeedDataSource"
    OnDeleteCommand="grdResource_DeleteCommand" ShowStatusBar="True" GridLines="None"
    OnItemDataBound="grdResource_ItemDataBound">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Like this i have 4 pageview tabs with indexes and every pageview tab contains a grid.If suppose i did changes in some x-grid and causes postback,then i need the x-grid should be shown after the postback. But i was showing the Resourcegrid.

**codebehind**

```
protected void RadMultiPage1_PageViewCreated(object sender, RadMultiPageEventArgs e)
{ 
    RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex = e.PageView.TabIndex;
}
```

but this event not firing in any case.
so how can i come back to the previous grid even when postback occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try set selected index in page_prerender.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //RadTab t1 = new RadTab();
        //RadMultiPage m1 = new RadMultiPage();
        m1.SelectedIndex = t1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please have a look at my problem. Also, I dont think now the problem is with javascript. I think somethings wrong with the RadTab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618022/javascript-not-working-with-radtabstrip-asp-net

Comment: @John Please check your above link/your question and let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know my solution can be helpful for this subject or not 
I tried all methods and finally find myself method,

i suggest if your problem not solved make java script function and then call it from code behind
My Sample :

```
   function OnClientClick1(i) {

        var tabstrip1 = $find("<%=RadTabStrip1.ClientID %>");

            tabstrip1.set_selectedIndex(1);

    }
```

and then make function on your code to call that

```
 private void ChangeTab(int index)
    {
        string scriptyKey = "Alert" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), scriptyKey, "OnClientClick1("+index.ToString()+");", true);

    }
```

I hope be useful