# JavaScript not working for second Tab/RadTab

Tags: javascript, tabs, telerik, jquery-ui-tabs, rad

I have two nested gridviews inside two radtabs, for this two nested views, I have a simple JavaScript for Expand and Collapse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function collapseExpand(obj) {
        var gvObject = document.getElementById(obj);
        var imageID = document.getElementById('image' + obj);

        if (gvObject.style.display == "none") {
            gvObject.style.display = "inline";
            imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_minus.jpg";
        }
        else {
            gvObject.style.display = "none";
            imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_plus.jpg";
        }
    }
```

The Java Script is working fine for the first RadGrid of the first tab. However, its not working with the second tab. I think the control is not able to transfer to the second grid. I think my problem is similar to

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/10/07/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions.aspx

I applied all the methods listed there but still its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(collapseExpand);
    } 
    function collapseExpand(obj) {
        var gvObject = document.getElementById(obj);
        var imageID = document.getElementById('image' + obj);

        if (gvObject.style.display == "none") {
            gvObject.style.display = "inline";
            imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_minus.jpg";
        }
        else {
            gvObject.style.display = "none";
            imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_plus.jpg";
        }
    }
```

Can somebody tell me what code to write to transfer or pass the control of javascript to the second tab?

Also, I am using Radtabs and RadPageView to display two grids in two tabs.

I am calling the Collapse Expand inside radtab

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" MultiPageID="RadMultipage1">
<Tabs>
<telerik:RadTab Text="Tab1" PageViewID="RadPageView1" OnLoad="Load1">
  </telerik:RadTab>
  <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab2" PageViewID="RadPageView2" >
 </telerik:RadTab>
 </Tabs>
 </telerik:RadTabStrip>
 <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultipage1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Width="100%" TabIndex="0">
<telerik:RadGrid ID="View1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100"
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
      OnItemDataBound="RadGrid2_ItemDataBound" >
   <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id">
   <Columns>
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <a href="javascript:collapseExpand('id_<%# Eval("id") %>');">
   <img id="imageSubId_<%# Eval("id") %>" alt="Click to show/hide orders" border="0" src="Images/bullet_toggle_plus.jpg" />
   </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" HeaderText="ID"/>
   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fname" HeaderText="First Name"/>
   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lname" HeaderText="Last Name"/>
   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOB" HeaderText="Date of Birth"/>
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">
            <div id="id_<%# Eval("id") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 10px;">
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="View2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="400"
                    GridLines="None" >
            <MasterTableView >
                    <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fname" HeaderText="First Name" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="mname" HeaderText="Middle Name" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lname" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkselect" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Remove"  CommandName="Split" OnClick="Button4_Click" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView >
             </telerik:RadGrid>
             </div>
             </td>
             </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
 </Columns>
 </MasterTableView>
 </telerik:RadGrid>
   </telerik:RadPageView>
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%">
 Same Code
 </telerik:RadPageView>
   </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Comment: Where are you calling collapseExpand?

Comment: @MaxPRafferty I am calling it inside Radtab. I did not add code for that since the question will become huge. I can send you the code for it personally if its okay for you to come on chat?

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with what you are passing into obj inside your repeater - as it is working for the first instance and not the second, it sounds like you may be setting multiple identical ID values.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty I added the whole code to the question. I have the exact same code in the RadPageView2 just datachanges for the second one. However, the javascript should work fine. but that's not happening.

Comment: In your rendered HTML, are those "ID_" anchors displaying correctly and uniquely for every row?

Comment: @MaxPRafferty Yes. I think the issue is with the control. Also, One peculiar thing is happening when I click the + sign on the second tab the first tab gridview is expanding.

Comment: Quick note, you have a bug where you grab the image ID - "image" should be imageSub.

Additionally, unless your control is setting some onClick events elsewhere (not out of the scope of possiblity), I don't really see how the control could be the problem. Once it reaches the browser, only javascript has influence over what gets fired and when. I would  try debugging in JS and hardcoding your anchor IDs into the control to see if you can force the second to open.

Comment: Have you tried with this demo ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618022/javascript-not-working-with-radtabstrip-asp-net/17696679#17696679

Comment: Yes. Thats working fine. The problem is with the second tab. Other wise JavaScript is working fine with the first tab. Are you getting me?

Comment: yes got it. I will provide solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function collapseExpand(obj, Id) {
            var gvObject = document.getElementById('div_' + Id + '_' + obj);
            var imageID = document.getElementById('imageSubId_' + Id + '_' + obj);

            if (gvObject.style.display == "none") {
                gvObject.style.display = "inline";
                imageID.src = "http://www.fimfiction-static.net/images/icons/collapse.png";
            }
            else {
                gvObject.style.display = "none";
                imageID.src = "http://jlpa.trinitylaban.ac.uk/WebCat_Images/English/Other/MiscD/admin-icon-expand.png";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

ASPX

```
  <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultipage1">
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab1" PageViewID="RadPageView1">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab2" PageViewID="RadPageView2">
        </telerik:RadTab>
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultipage1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Width="100%" TabIndex="0">
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal"
            OnNeedDataSource="GridView1_NeedDataSource">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a onclick="javascript:collapseExpand('<%# Eval("ID") %>','1');">
                                <img id="imageSubId_1_<%# Eval("ID") %>" alt="Click to show/hide orders" src="http://jlpa.trinitylaban.ac.uk/WebCat_Images/English/Other/MiscD/admin-icon-expand.png" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="100%">
                                    <div id="div_1_<%# Eval("ID") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 25px;">
                                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4"
                                            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnNeedDataSource="GridView1_NeedDataSource">
                                            <MasterTableView>
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="First Name" />
                                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkselect" runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Remove" CommandName="Split" />
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </MasterTableView>
                                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </telerik:RadPageView>
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%" TabIndex="0">
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal"
            OnNeedDataSource="GridView1_NeedDataSource">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a onclick="javascript:collapseExpand('<%# Eval("ID") %>','2');">
                                <img id="imageSubId_2_<%# Eval("ID") %>" alt="Click to show/hide orders" src="http://jlpa.trinitylaban.ac.uk/WebCat_Images/English/Other/MiscD/admin-icon-expand.png" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="100%">
                                    <div id="div_2_<%# Eval("ID") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 25px;">
                                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4"
                                            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnNeedDataSource="GridView1_NeedDataSource">
                                            <MasterTableView>
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="First Name" />
                                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkselect" runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Remove" CommandName="Split" />
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </MasterTableView>
                                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void GridView1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
    new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"},
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
    new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
     new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
    new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
};

    (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = data;
}
```